# Finding a number to add for division on both sides in a congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If we have to solve for x in  $3x ≡ 2 \pmod 5$, then we cannot just immediately divide both sides by 3. Because $\frac{2}3$ is not an integer.

Instead, we have to add multiples of 5 to either 3x or 2.

In this case, we can add 5 × 2 to 2.

$$3x ≡ 2 + 10 \pmod {5}$$
$$3x ≡ 12 \pmod {5}$$
Considering $gcd(3, 5) = 1$, we can divide both sides by 3.

$$x ≡ 4 \pmod {5}$$

But what happens if we cant easily find what number to add? In the first example, we easily know what to add, which is 10.

We have to solve for x in $83x ≡ 105 \pmod {120}$

Adding multiples of 120 to 105 is a tedious task to find if the result is a multiple of 83.

So my question is: How do we easily find what number to add?

Comment: Find the [inverse of 83 modulo 120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) i.e. find [Bezout coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) $a,b$ such that$$83a+120b=1,$$ and multiply both sides by this inverse.

Comment: Sorry, its my first time hearing those terms